# EditText.setSelection(end) brings no effect?

Tags: android, android-layout

I use the following code to set the `cursor` at the `end` of customEditText(`EditText`) but it brings no effect.

```
customEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                 if (hasFocus) {
                    String customEditTextText = customEditText.getText().toString();
                    int selection = customEditTextText.length();
                    customEditText.setSelection(selection);
                }
            }
});
```

Has anybody any ideas for that ?

Comment: try this  `customEditText.setSelection(customEditText.getText().length());`

Comment: No need to convert it to String..

Comment: Did you try it @Jacob???

Comment: android.widget.EditText.getText() returns Editable

Answer (score 14):

I had the same issue with an EditText inside an AlertDialog. The solution for me was this:

```
    mEditText.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mEditText.setSelection(mEditText.length());
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 12):

Works for me:

```
editText.requestFocus();
editText.setSelection(editText.getText().length());
```

Comment: absolutely brilliant!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Also, the right way to do it.

Comment: I don't understand this, his edittext already has focus

Answer (score 9):

This  works for me

```
mEditText.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        mEditText.setSelection(mEditText.getText().length());
                    }
                }, 50);
```

Don't know why, but need to use `postDelayed` to get it work.
just `post` doesn't working

Comment: none of the above worked for me . i had to use setSelection method on my edit text  in motion event runnable i was using to make the softKeyinput keyboard slide up when fragment opens up

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
customEditText.setSelection(customEditText.getText().length());
```

No need to convert it to String while Setting selection...

Comment: Try this `customEditText.setSelection(customEditText.length());`

Answer (score 1):

In order to setSelection to be work softkeyboard should be openned..

```
if(binding.edtListName.requestFocus()) {
            DataManager.showKeyboard(binding.edtListName,context);

        }
```

DataManager class:

```
public static void showKeyboard(EditText editText, Context context){
        editText.requestFocus();
        editText.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
                                 @Override public void run(){
                                     InputMethodManager keyboard=(InputMethodManager)context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                                     keyboard.showSoftInput(editText,0);

                                     if (editText.getText().toString().length() > 0 ) {

                                         editText.setSelection(0,editText.getText().toString().length());
                                     }
                                 }
                             }
                ,400);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
customEditText.setSelection(customEditText.getText().length()-1);
```

Comment: I believe it will not give him correct solution, but since its customedittext, there is some other issue like layout. so a trial approach. the code what is posted is same what you commented.

Comment: Sorry, not same as my code, but same what is asked in question. Also i had similar issue when using rounded customized edit text, but strangely cursor was not visible, but issue was something else. Since i cannot comment on questions, i have to write it as an answer.

Comment: Okk.. @essess let him try both the answers..I just asked you..Sorry if you felt bad..

Comment: He wants to point to the end of the text. Since 0 is left of the beginning of the text, text.length points to the right of the text which is what the goal is (as far as I understand)

Answer (score 0):

Try this....

```
editText.requestFocus();
```

**Note : It automatically set cursor to last position of edittext.**